# Openerp : change the logo

Tags: odoo

I use openerp 6.1 GTK.

I try to change the logo, adress1, adress2 in quotations and invoices,

I was changed it directly in openerp gtk, but today I forget the way, I searched in settings and partners...

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change this kind of information, you should go to Administration / Companies. Open the main company and change the information into this form, then save.

For the addresses in reports, there is a RML header field on the company form view.